# Response containing object *and* type

Tags: c#, api, response, .net-6.0

I'm writing an API in which I want my methods to return objects which also contain the type of the object. For this I created a `DataWrapper` class where the `Body` property contains the actual object and the `Type` property contains the type - thanks to this I want to be able to process the response in the frontend easier.

The problem is, .NET seems to have a problem serializing the `Type` to JSON when generating a response and just sends status code '500' to the frontend.

The frontend is written in Flutter and I'm planning to manually check the type for now (will parse the string from the response JSON and then decide what to do next in a series of `if` statements) and will create some mapper later (Flutter's types are very similar to .NET's).

My questions are:

1. How to fix this and send the object type to the frontend?
2. Is there a more correct (industry standard?) way of achieving what I want?

An example of my method in which I send the response with the wrapped object:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<DataWrapper>> RegisterUser([FromBody] UserDto newUser)
{
    DataWrapper result = await _userProcessor.SaveNewUserAsync(newUser);
    return (result.Type == typeof(SecurityToken)) ? Ok(result) : BadRequest(result);
}
```

And the `DataWrapper` class:

```
public class DataWrapper
{
    public Type Type { get => _type; set => _type = value; }
    private Type _type;

    object _body;
    public object Body
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ChangeType(_body, _type);
        }
        set
        {
            _body = value;
            _type = value.GetType();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the nature of the front-end? Most front-ends have no practical way to use a .NET type, so you'd usually use a more technology agnostic way of communicating types, such as via schemas and/or MIME types.

Comment: Is the client written in C# and do you have the same type in client? If both answers are yes, you can serialize the type's full name (or an AssemblyQualifiedName indeed).

Comment: I've updated my post to answer what frontend I'm using.

Comment: I would argue that this is a very bad design which will only complicate life for you. _"How to fix this and send the object type to the frontend?"_ - you should not, object type is internal implementation detail and should not be a concern for FE.

Comment: If something was missing in the request, how can I inform the fronend about what specifically? I believe I still need some kind of data wrapper which will add a message.